# How to find and delete the duplicates from lists of vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, linear-algebra, vector

What I want to do is to take a list of vectors:

```
u={{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0}}
v={{1,1,1,1},{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0}}
```

I want to find the duplicates between u and v and then delete them from u. I am not sure why my method is not working

```
duplicates= Intersection[u,v]
u'=DeleteCases[u,duplicates]
```

But this is not working. I am not sure if it has something to do with the structure of the list, but when I use Flatten[u,1] (and for v) it gives me just a 12 component vector instead of three 4 component vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since V 13.1 there is `DeleteElements`

```
 u = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}};
 v = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}};

DeleteElements[u, v]
```

{{0, 0, 1, 0}}

Alternatively you can use

```
DeleteCases[Alternatives @@ v] @ u
```

{{0, 0, 1, 0}}

If sort order isn't important it's simply

```
Complement[u, v]
```

{{0, 0, 1, 0}}

To see this difference:

```
u = {{2, 2, 2, 2}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}};

DeleteElements[u, v]
```

{{2, 2, 2, 2}, {0, 0, 1, 0}}

But

```
Complement[u, v]
```

{{0, 0, 1, 0}, {2, 2, 2, 2}}